# Make pip install modules even if one fails

Tags: python, pip

I'm using `pip` to install modules from a requirements file produced with `pip freeze`. However the problem sometimes it's unable to install or download one module and then everything fails and doesn't install anything. Is there a way to make it install the modules that satisfy the requirements?

Answer (score 2):

With pip only, I would say no. pip and Python packages generally are designed to work in such a way that you *might* need dependencies installed in order to install the package itself. Thus, they don't have an option to try despite of failures.

However, `pip install -r requirements.txt` simply goes through the file line-by-line. You can iterate the every single item yourself and call `pip install` for it, without caring the result (was the installation successfully or not). With shell scripting this could be done e.g.:

```
 cat requirements.txt|xargs pip install
```

The example does not understand comments, spaces, etc. so you might need to how something more complex in place for a real-life scenario.

Alternative you can simply run `pip` in loop until it gives a successful return value.

But as a *real* solution I would recommend you to set up your own Python package mirror server, or a local cache - which would be another question.